# "metaphoric" versus "metaphorical"

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, ic-ical

Is there a difference between the words "metaphoric" and "metaphorical"?  I'm reading an essay in which "metaphoric" is used.  But that sounded a little odd to me.  "Metaphorical" sounds better.  They're both in the dictionary.

Comment: There's no difference in meaning. That means it's speaker's choice. I.e, you should use the one that sounds better **to you** in any given context. Different choice each time, as the context changes. It's an awesome responsibility to exercise such decision-making, but that's language for you. No real general rules for anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> There is no difference between **metaphoric** and metaphorical, *but
>   you are right*, ***metaphorical*** is more commonly used.

This [**ngram** graphs](http://grammarist.com/spelling/metaphoric-metaphorical/) the use of metaphoric and metaphorical in English-language books published in the 20th century.

- Some writers will always favor it for its brevity, but metaphorical
  prevails for now.

  - They seem to be used quite interchangeably.

(grammarist.com)